# Prestashop, synchronize the local stores with a global store

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have 3 local stores, each stores have one prestashop e-commerce. 
65% of their products are the same and the rest changes regarding to the store.
I would like to find the way to create a fourth prestashop e-commerce  which sell the products of all the 3 stores, manage the stock and notify the different stores when an order is created.
Each store has to manage their special products ( descriptions, pictures and prices). For the products which are the same between each stores, the price, description and pictures are exactly the same.

Is it possible?

Thanks!!

**EDIT**

By local stores, I mean real physical stores. These stores impemented in three differents places have a online store on the subdomaine : mydomaine.com/city1 , mydomaine.com/city2 , mydomaine.com/city3.

For instance the store 1 has the product 1, the store 2 the product 2, the store 3 the product 3.

And the online site 4 should have the products 1,2,3.

I would like to create a fourth online story which regroup the products of the three other online stores. The stock on the fourth online store  for the same products, should be the sum of the product available one each local store.

For instance, the store based in the city 1, could add a new special product ( price, description, stock) in its online store ( mydomaine.com/city1). ( special product : product only sold in one location ) This product should be directly accessible on the fourth online store ( the local managers have no access to the fourth online store). The thorny point is here : if a customer order on the fourth online store, the local stores which have the products involved in the customer order should be notified to send the products. And If a product is sold on a local online store ( for instance, mydomaine.com/city2) the stock of the fourth online store should be updated.

The stock for each online store is updated everyday to match the store stocks. For instance, the store in the city 1 will update every day the stocks of their products available online regarding to their sales of the day in their brick and mortgage store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prestashop includes a [MultiStore functionality](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Multiple+Shops).

You can create a single website with 4 different shops. You then can import all your products and link those products to your shops (You can link a product to one or more shops). You can manage prices and stocks independently for each shops as well.

Please let me know if you have more questions on the subject.

Here are some links:

- [Managing Multiple Shops](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Multiple+Shops)
- [Advanced Stock Management](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Advanced+Stock+Management)

Comment: Hi Florian, Thanks for the answer. The problem is that the managers will not have access to the fourth store.  I eddited my question. please let me know whether you understand what I am saying. ( I could quickly summarize in French.. ) Best.

Comment: Ok, I understand your requirements. If I add to do this I would go with a MultiStore as I said in my answer. Prestashop already Implements this kind of functionnality with the Advanced Stock Management, you can define multiple warehouse (your physical stocks) linked to different shops. And create different accesses for your employees to access their related shops. Each shop will have its own domain name or subdomain and its own theme.

But if you want to keep 4 different Prestashop you will have to use the api system. In my opinion it will be less maintenable but it's doable ;).

Comment: Do you have any more questions? To summaries you have two options: create a unique Prestashop with MultiStore or create a new Prestashop updated via the API system for stocks. Both can be done.

Comment: Thanks Florian, I see what you mean. If I work with the multiStore, Can I manage the access of the different managers of the backend? In order to let them see and change only the products related to their local stores ? I guess it will be more efficient to use the multistore than working with the API.

Comment: Yes you will ! You can restrict access as you want. The big work will be to merge all your shops into a unique Prestashop.

Comment: Hi Florian, I tried it, I created a multi store with different access. But I have no idea of how I can share the products of my local stores with the fourth store.. Do you know how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Hi, you need to set your fourth shop as the default one and you need to create all your products under "All shops" (you can switch between shops in the header bar). Your product will then be available from all shops and can be activated and edited independently from each one of those.

Comment: Your store managers will then have the possibility to activate the product they sale and set their quantities.